# C: Can't link head and tail in double linked list with external function [addressing issue]

Tags: c, list, double

I made a simplification of my double linked list. My double linked list is a structure that has a head and a tail as nodes.

There is a function to create the list and return it. In the same function I do the linkage between the tail and the head nodes. The problem is that when I return the list(so go outside the function), all the links are gone or they just point to the nodes of the list that was temporarily created in the function. Is my guess correct? If so how am I going to bypass this problem?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node{        /*a node of a list*/
    int number;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;

typedef struct list{    /*the list structure that holds only the head and tail*/
    node head;
    node tail;
} list;

list createList(){
    list newList;
    newList.head.prev=NULL;
    newList.head.next=&newList.tail; /*first node points to the second*/
    newList.tail.prev=&newList.head; /*second node points to the first*/
    newList.tail.next=NULL;
    puts("--CREATE LIST FUNC--");
    printf("Head element address: %p\n", &newList.head);
    printf("Tail element address: %p\n", &newList.tail);
    printf("Head element points here: %p\n\n\n", newList.head.next);
    return newList;
}

int main(){
    list numbers=createList();
    puts("--MAIN FUNC--");
    printf("Head element address: %p\n", &numbers.head);
    printf("Tail element address: %p\n", &numbers.tail);
    printf("Head element points here: %p\n", numbers.head.next);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct; `newList` goes out of scope when the function ends.  The function returns a copy of the `list` object, but the pointer members will still point at the *original* object.

You either need to allocate a `list` on the heap and return by pointer (remembering to free the memory at some point), or take a pointer-to-`list` as an argument, and modify a `list` that the caller owns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` and `free()`), since you can't return the newly created list item by value.

Comment: You can; the problem is that the compiler only performs a shallow copy.

Comment: @Oli No, in this case you can't since the address of the variable will change.

Comment: Yes, and that's a problem because of the shallow copy!

Answer (score 0):

you can't create the list as `list newlist` inside your function because that is on the stack. You need to return a pointer to a list. The variables on the stack are not guaranteed to be there once your function returns.

```
list* createList(){
    list* newList = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    newList->head.prev=NULL;
    newList->head.next=newList->tail; /*first node points to the second*/
    newList->tail.prev=newList->head; /*second node points to the first*/
    newList->tail.next=NULL;
    puts("--CREATE LIST FUNC--");
    printf("Head element address: %p\n", newList->head);
    printf("Tail element address: %p\n", newList->tail);
    printf("Head element points here: %p\n\n\n", newList->head.next);
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: whoops. this is C not C++. fixed.